# Subgroup of idele class group is open

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

On page 380 of Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory* the author states that the subgroup $$\prod_{\mathfrak{p} \nmid \infty} U_\mathfrak{p} \times \prod_{\mathfrak{p} \mid \infty} K_\mathfrak{p}^\times$$ of the idèle class group $I_K$ of a number field $K$ is open. Here $\mathfrak{p} \mid \infty$ means that $\mathfrak{p}$ denotes an equivalence class of archimedean absolute values and $\mathfrak{p} \nmid \infty$ means that $\mathfrak{p}$ denotes an equivalence class of non-archimedean absolute values; moreover $U_\mathfrak{p}$ is the group of units of the completion $K_\mathfrak{p}$ (i.e. the elements with absolute value equal to 1).

I can't see why the subgroup is open. Does anyone know how to prove this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm confused by what you've written in brackets. What is your definition of the topology on the ideles?

Comment: I think Neukirch defines the topology on $I_K$ as the induced topology that it bears as a subspace of $\prod_{\mathfrak{p}} K_\mathfrak{p}$. I deleted the comment in the bracket again, it might be more confusing than helping.

Comment: In my copy of Neukirch, on p361, just before prop IV.1.5, he defines the topology in a way that makes your subgroup open by definition. The topology is definitely not just the one induced from the product topology. Crucially, with the product topology, $I_K$ is not locally compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$ containing all the infinite places (or primes as Neukirch says, and let $$I_K^S = \prod\limits_{v \in S} K_v^{\ast} \prod\limits_{v \not\in S} \mathcal O_v^{\ast}$$ Give $I_K^S$ the product topology.  Then all the $I_K^S$ are subsets of $$\prod\limits_v K_v$$ and $I_K$ is the union of all the $I_K^S$ : $S$ is a finite set of places containing the infinite places.  By *definition*, a subset $E$ of $I_K$ is open if and only if for all $S$, $E \cap I_K^S$ is open in $I_K^S$.  Let $S_{\infty}$ be the set of infinite places of $K$.  Then the set you want to show is open is $I_K^{S_{\infty}}$.  If $S$ is any set as above, then $$I_K^{S_{\infty}} \cap I_K^S = I_K^S$$ is of course open in $I_K^S$.